# Why is a SystemStackError caused with a has_many association in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I stumbled over a SystemStackError and found where it is caused in the source code. Though, I did not quite understand why it happens. Maybe you can help me.

Here is the scenario:
There are two models `Facility` and `Location` given by their model definitions in the following.

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :facility
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :facility
end

class Facility < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations
end
```

Now I create an object of each class in the Rails console: `rails c`.

```
location = Location.create(...)
facility = Facility.create(...)
```

Then I want to associate both with each other.

```
location.facility = facility
facility.locations << location
```

I cannot execute the last command when I executed the first before - it raises a `SystemStackError: stack level too deep`. Though, I can run the association commands separate from each other or sequential but in reverse order. The problem is that I cannot add the `location` again. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do both?

This line:

```
facility.locations << location
```

Will already set the location's facility to be the specified `facility`. Both lines in this case are doing the same thing. What I would recommend doing is to use the association builder, like this:

```
facility.locations.create!(...)
```

This way, Rails takes care of setting the `facility_id` field, rather than you doing a manual assignment after it.

Comment: I did not know I can call `create` concatinated this way. - I know "the locations's facility is already set" but why is it a problem to make it redundant?

Comment: It works as long as the referenced object is not nil. The exclamation point is not mandatory here.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that I would suspect here is that the has_many association is really has_too_many. In other words, you may have too many locations in the relationship.

In fact, given the code you posted, you seem to have created an infinite loop of associations. You wrote:

`accepts_nested_attributes_for :facility`

I am assuming that this causes ActiveRecord to open the facility attribute where it finds another location with yet another facility attribute ad infinitem. before you dig too deeply, try this to see if it works:

```
facility.locations << location
location.facility = facility
```

However, be wary because this might just push the stack error to some other place in the app. If you Google for that error message you can find several people who have run into infinite recursion problems, generally related to saving a record.

Comment: I already tried your later suggestion: "... or sequential but in reverse order." The question is, why does it not work the other way around. - Can `accepts_nested_attributes_for` cause problems although I am in the Rails console?

Comment: If you set the facility attribute second, then when you add the location to the facility.locations attribute, there is no circular reference to follow. I think that you need to rethink your design here. Having each object nested in the other doesn't really make sense.